# How can I take a JSON schema that can build a form with dynamic objects in addition to dynamic arrays?

Tags: javascript, json, forms, jsonschema, formbuilder

I have seen how a JSON schema can be used to build dynamic arrays.

I'm looking to create a JSON web form from a JSON schema that allows for **objects** (dictionaries) to be expandable just like the case for arrays.

To illustrate, consider the demo site: http://brutusin.org/json-forms/#2.

Notice that the schema for the form on line 69 is of type `array`. And, its items are of type `object`. What I want is to have the same thing but allow the user of the form to define both the key and the value in the form. This would allow me to dynamically build up dictionaries. In short, I wish I could change line 69 from `array` to `object`, add some additional schema definitions to indicate the key properties, and have it generate JSON including expandable objects.

But, perhaps my issue is in understanding the [JSON schema capabilities](http://json-schema.org/). Is there something in the schema definition that prescribes having dynamic objects (where both the key and the corresponding object structure would need to be entered into the generated form)?

And, to make it clear what I'm trying to do, imagine the schema:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

It can be used to generate:

```
[
  "abc"
]
```

I would like a schema that can generate a form that can produce a JSON result such as:

```
{
  "key1": "abc",
  "key2": "xyz",
}
```

where the `"abc"` or `"xyz"` can be any valid JSON type or complex structure (with a corresponding change in the schema) and there can be an arbitrary number of key/value pairs in the object.

**So, the question is:** How can I take a JSON schema that can build a form with dynamic objects in addition to dynamic arrays? Any example implementations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand, are you looking to create the Key/Value inputs like in this sample, and then have the user input the custom key and its value, and have that stored as an object inside an array and then converted to JSON, or are you want to actually display JSON instead of the inputs..?

```js
var schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "pageNum": {
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "Page number",
            "description": "Page number to be queried, `1-based`. See [Pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) for more details",
            "default": 1,
            "required": true
        },
        "pageSize": {
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "Page size",
            "description": "Number of records per page",
            "required": true,
            "default": 50,
            "enum": [
                10,
                25,
                50,
                100
            ]
        },
        "selectedFacetValues": {
            "type": "array",
            "title": "Query terms",
            "minItems": 2,
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "description": "Query item",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "facetName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Field name",
                        "description": "Indexed field name",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "matchAllNull": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "title": "Match nulls"
                    },
                    "matchAllNotNull": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "title": "Match not nulls"
                    },
                    "facetValues": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "title": "Field values",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "title": "Value"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "included": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "title": "Included"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sorts": {
            "type": "array",
            "title": "Sorting",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "key": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Key"
                    },
                    "val": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var BrutusinForms = brutusin["json-forms"];
var bf = BrutusinForms.create(schema);
var container = document.getElementById('container');

bf.render(container, []);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='http://github.com/brutusin/json-forms/tree/master/dist/css/brutusin-json-forms.min.css'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
if("undefined"==typeof brutusin)window.brutusin=new Object;else if("object"!=typeof brutusin)throw"brutusin global variable already exists";!function(){String.prototype.startsWith||(String.prototype.startsWith=function(e,t){return t=t||0,this.indexOf(e,t)===t}),String.prototype.endsWith||(String.prototype.endsWith=function(e,t){var r=this.toString();(void 0===t||t>r.length)&&(t=r.length),t-=e.length;var n=r.indexOf(e,t);return-1!==n&&n===t}),String.prototype.includes||(String.prototype.includes=function(){"use strict";return-1!==String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this,arguments)}),String.prototype.format||(String.prototype.format=function(){for(var e=this,t=0;t<arguments.length;t++){var r=new RegExp("\\{"+t+"\\}","gi");e=e.replace(r,arguments[t])}return e});var BrutusinForms=new Object;BrutusinForms.messages={validationError:"Validation error",required:"This field is **required**",invalidValue:"Invalid field value",addpropNameExistent:"This property is already present in the object",addpropNameRequired:"A name is required",minItems:"At least `{0}` items are required",maxItems:"At most `{0}` items are allowed",pattern:"Value does not match pattern: `{0}`",minLength:"Value must be **at least** `{0}` characters long",maxLength:"Value must be **at most** `{0}` characters long",multipleOf:"Value must be **multiple of** `{0}`",minimum:"Value must be **greater or equal than** `{0}`",exclusiveMinimum:"Value must be **greater than** `{0}`",maximum:"Value must be **lower or equal than** `{0}`",exclusiveMaximum:"Value must be **lower than** `{0}`",minProperties:"At least `{0}` properties are required",maxProperties:"At most `{0}` properties are allowed",uniqueItems:"Array items must be unique",addItem:"Add item","true":"True","false":"False"},BrutusinForms.decorators=new Array,BrutusinForms.addDecorator=function(e){BrutusinForms.decorators[BrutusinForms.decorators.length]=e},BrutusinForms.onResolutionStarted=function(e){},BrutusinForms.onResolutionFinished=function(e){},BrutusinForms.onValidationError=function(e,t){e.focus(),e.className.includes(" error")||(e.className+=" error"),alert(t)},BrutusinForms.onValidationSuccess=function(e){e.className=e.className.replace(" error","")},BrutusinForms.postRender=null,BrutusinForms.instances=new Array,BrutusinForms.create=function(schema){function validateDepencyMapIsAcyclic(){function e(t,r,n){if(r.hasOwnProperty(n))return void(error="Schema dependency graph has cycles");if(r[n]=null,!t.hasOwnProperty(n)){t[n]=null;var a=dependencyMap[n];if(a)for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)e(t,r,a[i]);delete r[n]}}var t=new Object;for(var r in dependencyMap)t.hasOwnProperty(r)||e(t,new Object,r)}function appendChild(e,t,r){e.appendChild(t);for(var n=0;n<BrutusinForms.decorators.length;n++)BrutusinForms.decorators[n](t,r)}function createPseudoSchema(e){var t=new Object;for(var r in e)"items"!==r&&"properties"!==r&&"additionalProperties"!==r&&("pattern"===r?t[r]=new RegExp(e[r]):t[r]=e[r]);return t}function getDefinition(e){var t=e.split("/"),r=root;for(var n in t)"0"!==n&&(r=r[t[n]]);return r}function containsStr(e,t){for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)if(e[r]==t)return!0;return!1}function renameRequiredPropeties(e){if(e)if(e.hasOwnProperty("oneOf"))for(var t in e.oneOf)renameRequiredPropeties(e.oneOf[t]);else if(e.hasOwnProperty("$ref")){var r=getDefinition(e.$ref);renameRequiredPropeties(r)}else if("object"===e.type){if(e.properties){e.hasOwnProperty("required")&&Array.isArray(e.required)&&(e.requiredProperties=e.required,delete e.required);for(var n in e.properties)renameRequiredPropeties(e.properties[n])}if(e.patternProperties)for(var a in e.patternProperties){var i=e.patternProperties[a];(i.hasOwnProperty("type")||i.hasOwnProperty("$ref")||i.hasOwnProperty("oneOf"))&&renameRequiredPropeties(e.patternProperties[a])}e.additionalProperties&&(e.additionalProperties.hasOwnProperty("type")||e.additionalProperties.hasOwnProperty("oneOf"))&&renameRequiredPropeties(e.additionalProperties)}else"array"===e.type&&renameRequiredPropeties(e.items)}function populateSchemaMap(e,t){var r=createPseudoSchema(t);if(r.$id=e,schemaMap[e]=r,t){if(t.hasOwnProperty("oneOf")){r.oneOf=new Array,r.type="oneOf";for(var n in t.oneOf){var a=e+"."+n;r.oneOf[n]=a,populateSchemaMap(a,t.oneOf[n])}}else if(t.hasOwnProperty("$ref")){var i=getDefinition(t.$ref);if(i){if(t.hasOwnProperty("title")||t.hasOwnProperty("description")){var o={};for(var s in i)o[s]=i[s];t.hasOwnProperty("title")&&(o.title=t.title),t.hasOwnProperty("description")&&(o.description=t.description),i=o}populateSchemaMap(e,i)}}else if("object"===t.type){if(t.properties){r.properties=new Object;for(var s in t.properties){var a=e+"."+s;r.properties[s]=a;var u=t.properties[s];t.requiredProperties&&(containsStr(t.requiredProperties,s)?u.required=!0:u.required=!1),populateSchemaMap(a,u)}}if(t.patternProperties){r.patternProperties=new Object;for(var l in t.patternProperties){var d=e+"["+l+"]";r.patternProperties[l]=d;var p=t.patternProperties[l];p.hasOwnProperty("type")||p.hasOwnProperty("$ref")||p.hasOwnProperty("oneOf")?populateSchemaMap(d,t.patternProperties[l]):populateSchemaMap(d,SCHEMA_ANY)}}if(t.additionalProperties){var a=e+"[*]";r.additionalProperties=a,t.additionalProperties.hasOwnProperty("type")||t.additionalProperties.hasOwnProperty("oneOf")?populateSchemaMap(a,t.additionalProperties):populateSchemaMap(a,SCHEMA_ANY)}}else"array"===t.type&&(r.items=e+"[#]",populateSchemaMap(r.items,t.items));if(t.hasOwnProperty("dependsOn")){null===t.dependsOn&&(t.dependsOn=["$"]);for(var c=new Array,n=0;n<t.dependsOn.length;n++)t.dependsOn[n]?t.dependsOn[n].startsWith("$")?c[n]=t.dependsOn[n]:e.endsWith("]")?c[n]=e+"."+t.dependsOn[n]:c[n]=e.substring(0,e.lastIndexOf("."))+"."+t.dependsOn[n]:c[n]="$";schemaMap[e].dependsOn=c;for(var n=0;n<c.length;n++){var m=dependencyMap[c[n]];m||(m=new Array,dependencyMap[c[n]]=m),m[m.length]=e}}}}function renderTitle(e,t,r){if(e&&t){var n=document.createElement("label");"any"!==r.type&&"object"!==r.type&&"array"!==r.type&&(n.htmlFor=getInputId());var a=document.createTextNode(t+":");if(appendChild(n,a,r),r.description&&(n.title=r.description),r.required){var i=document.createElement("sup");appendChild(i,document.createTextNode("*"),r),appendChild(n,i,r),n.className="required"}appendChild(e,n,r)}}function getInputId(){return formId+"_"+inputCounter}function validate(e){var t=!0;if(e.hasOwnProperty("getValidationError")){var r=e.getValidationError();r?(BrutusinForms.onValidationError(e,r),t=!1):BrutusinForms.onValidationSuccess(e)}if(e.childNodes)for(var n=0;n<e.childNodes.length;n++)validate(e.childNodes[n])||(t=!1);return t}function clear(e){if(e)for(;e.firstChild;)e.removeChild(e.firstChild)}function render(e,t,r,n,a,i){var o=getSchemaId(r),s=getSchema(o);renderInfoMap[o]=new Object,renderInfoMap[o].titleContainer=e,renderInfoMap[o].container=t,renderInfoMap[o].parentObject=n,renderInfoMap[o].propertyProvider=a,renderInfoMap[o].value=i,clear(e),clear(t);var u=renderers[s.type];if(u&&!s.dependsOn)s.title?renderTitle(e,s.title,s):a&&renderTitle(e,a.getValue(),s),i||(i="undefined"!=typeof initialValue&&null!==initialValue?getInitialValue(r):s["default"]),u(t,r,n,a,i);else if(s.$ref&&obj.schemaResolver){var l=function(e){if(e&&e.hasOwnProperty(r)&&JSON.stringify(schemaMap[r])!==JSON.stringify(e[r])){cleanSchemaMap(r),cleanData(r),populateSchemaMap(r,e[r]);var t=renderInfoMap[r];t&&render(t.titleContainer,t.container,r,t.parentObject,t.propertyProvider,t.value)}BrutusinForms.onResolutionFinished(n)};BrutusinForms.onResolutionStarted(n),obj.schemaResolver([r],obj.getData(),l)}}function createPropertyProvider(e,t){var r=new Object;return r.getValue=e,r.onchange=t,r}function getInitialValue(id){var ret;try{eval("ret = initialValue"+id.substring(1))}catch(e){ret=null}return ret}function getValue(schema,input){if("function"==typeof input.getValue)return input.getValue();var value;return value="select"===input.tagName.toLowerCase()?input.options[input.selectedIndex].value:input.value,""===value?null:("integer"===schema.type?(value=parseInt(value),isFinite(value)||(value=null)):"number"===schema.type?(value=parseFloat(value),isFinite(value)||(value=null)):"boolean"===schema.type?"input"===input.tagName.toLowerCase()?(value=input.checked,value||(value=!1)):"select"===input.tagName.toLowerCase()&&(value="true"===input.value?!0:"false"===input.value?!1:null):"any"===schema.type&&value&&eval("value="+value),value)}function getSchemaId(e){return e.replace(/\["[^"]*"\]/g,"[*]").replace(/\[\d*\]/g,"[#]")}function getParentSchemaId(e){return e.substring(0,e.lastIndexOf("."))}function getSchema(e){return schemaMap[e]}function cleanSchemaMap(e){for(var t in schemaMap)e.startsWith(t)&&delete schemaMap[t]}function cleanData(e){var t=new Expression(e);t.visit(data,function(e,t,r){delete t[r]})}function onDependencyChanged(e,t){var r=dependencyMap[e];if(r&&obj.schemaResolver){var n=function(e){if(e)for(var r in e)if(JSON.stringify(schemaMap[r])!==JSON.stringify(e[r])){cleanSchemaMap(r),cleanData(r),populateSchemaMap(r,e[r]);var n=renderInfoMap[r];n&&render(n.titleContainer,n.container,r,n.parentObject,n.propertyProvider,n.value)}BrutusinForms.onResolutionFinished(t)};BrutusinForms.onResolutionStarted(t),obj.schemaResolver(r,obj.getData(),n)}}function Expression(e){function t(e){if(null===e)return null;for(var t=new Array,r=null,n=0,a=0;a<e.length;a++)'"'===e.charAt(a)?null===r?r='"':'"'===r&&(r=null,t[t.length]=e.substring(n,a+1).trim(),n=a+1):"'"===e.charAt(a)?null===r?r="'":"'"===r&&(r=null,t[t.length]=e.substring(n,a+1).trim(),n=a+1):"["===e.charAt(a)?null===r&&(n!==a&&(t[t.length]=e.substring(n,a).trim()),t[t.length]="[",n=a+1):"]"===e.charAt(a)?null===r&&(n!==a&&(t[t.length]=e.substring(n,a).trim()),t[t.length]="]",n=a+1):"."===e.charAt(a)?null===r&&(n!==a&&(t[t.length]=e.substring(n,a).trim()),n=a+1):a===e.length-1&&(t[t.length]=e.substring(n,a+1).trim());return t}(null===e||0===e.length||"."===e)&&(e="$");for(var r=new Array,n=t(e),a=!1,i=0,o="",s=0;s<n.length;s++){var u=n[s];if("["===u){if(a)throw"Error parsing expression '"+e+"': Nested [ found";a=!0,i=0,o+=u}else if("]"===u){if(!a)throw"Error parsing expression '"+e+"': Unbalanced ] found";a=!1,o+=u,r[r.length]=o,o=""}else if(a){if(i>0)throw"Error parsing expression '"+e+"': Multiple tokens found inside a bracket";o+=u,i++}else r[r.length]=u;if(s===n.length-1&&a)throw"Error parsing expression '"+e+"': Unbalanced [ found"}this.exp=e,this.queue=r,this.visit=function(e,t){function r(e,n,a,i,o){if(null!=a){var s=n.shift();if("$"===s){e="$";var s=n.shift()}if(s)if(Array.isArray(a)){if(!s.startsWith("["))throw"Node '"+e+"' is of type array";var u=s.substring(1,s.length-1);if(u.equals("#"))for(var l=0;l<a.length;l++){var d=a[l];r(e+s,n.slice(0),d,a,l),r(e+"["+l+"]",n.slice(0),d,a,l)}else if("$"===u){var d=a[a.length-1];r(e+s,n.slice(0),d,a,a.length-1)}else{var p=parseInt(u);if(isNaN(p))throw"Element '"+u+"' of node '"+e+"' is not an integer, or the '$' last element symbol,  or the wilcard symbol '#'";if(0>p)throw"Element '"+u+"' of node '"+e+"' is lower than zero";var d=a[p];r(e+s,n.slice(0),d,a,p)}}else{if("object"!=typeof a)throw"boolean"==typeof a||"number"==typeof a||"string"==typeof a?"Node is leaf but still are tokens remaining: "+s:"Node type '"+typeof a+"' not supported for index field '"+e+"'";if("[*]"===s)for(var c in a){var d=a[c];r(e+s,n.slice(0),d,a,c),r(e+'["'+c+'"]',n.slice(0),d,a,c)}else{var d;if(s.startsWith("[")){var u=s.substring(1,s.length-1);if(!u.startsWith('"')&&!u.startsWith("'"))throw"Element '"+u+"' of node '"+e+"' must be a string expression or wilcard '*'";u=u.substring(1,u.length()-1),e+=s,d=a[u]}else e=e.length>0?e+"."+s:s,d=a[s];r(e,n,d,a,s)}}else t(a,i,o)}}r(this.exp,this.queue,e)}}var SCHEMA_ANY={type:"any"},obj=new Object,schemaMap=new Object,dependencyMap=new Object,renderInfoMap=new Object,container,data,error,initialValue,inputCounter=0,root=schema,formId="BrutusinForms#"+BrutusinForms.instances.length;renameRequiredPropeties(schema),populateSchemaMap("$",schema),validateDepencyMapIsAcyclic();var renderers=new Object;return renderers.integer=function(e,t,r,n,a){renderers.string(e,t,r,n,a)},renderers.number=function(e,t,r,n,a){renderers.string(e,t,r,n,a)},renderers.any=function(e,t,r,n,a){renderers.string(e,t,r,n,a)},renderers.string=function(e,t,r,n,a){var i,o=getSchemaId(t),s=getParentSchemaId(o),u=getSchema(o),l=getSchema(s);if("any"===u.type)i=document.createElement("textarea"),a&&(i.value=JSON.stringify(a,null,4),u.readOnly&&(i.disabled=!0));else if(u.media)i=document.createElement("input"),i.type="file",appendChild(i,d,u);else if(u["enum"]){if(i=document.createElement("select"),!u.required){var d=document.createElement("option"),p=document.createTextNode("");d.value="",appendChild(d,p,u),appendChild(i,d,u)}for(var c=0,m=0;m<u["enum"].length;m++){var d=document.createElement("option"),p=document.createTextNode(u["enum"][m]);d.value=u["enum"][m],appendChild(d,p,u),appendChild(i,d,u),a&&u["enum"][m]===a&&(c=m,u.required||c++,u.readOnly&&(i.disabled=!0))}1===u["enum"].length?i.selectedIndex=1:i.selectedIndex=c}else{if(i=document.createElement("input"),"integer"===u.type||"number"===u.type)i.type="number",i.step=u.step?""+u.step:"any","number"!=typeof a&&(a=null);else if("date-time"===u.format)try{i.type="datetime-local"}catch(f){i.type="text"}else"email"===u.format?i.type="email":"text"===u.format?i=document.createElement("textarea"):i.type="text";null!==a&&"undefined"!=typeof a&&(i.value=a,u.readOnly&&(i.disabled=!0))}return i.schema=o,i.setAttribute("autocorrect","off"),i.getValidationError=function(){try{var e=getValue(u,i);if(null===e){if(u.required){if(!l||"object"!==l.type)return BrutusinForms.messages.required;if(l.required)return BrutusinForms.messages.required;for(var t in r)if(null!==r[t])return BrutusinForms.messages.required}}else{if(u.pattern&&!u.pattern.test(e))return BrutusinForms.messages.pattern.format(u.pattern.source);if(u.minLength&&(!e||u.minLength>e.length))return BrutusinForms.messages.minLength.format(u.minLength);if(u.maxLength&&e&&u.maxLength<e.length)return BrutusinForms.messages.maxLength.format(u.maxLength)}if(null!==e&&!isNaN(e)){if(u.multipleOf&&e%u.multipleOf!==0)return BrutusinForms.messages.multipleOf.format(u.multipleOf);if(u.hasOwnProperty("maximum")){if(u.exclusiveMaximum&&e>=u.maximum)return BrutusinForms.messages.exclusiveMaximum.format(u.maximum);if(!u.exclusiveMaximum&&e>u.maximum)return BrutusinForms.messages.maximum.format(u.maximum)}if(u.hasOwnProperty("minimum")){if(u.exclusiveMinimum&&e<=u.minimum)return BrutusinForms.messages.exclusiveMinimum.format(u.minimum);if(!u.exclusiveMinimum&&e<u.minimum)return BrutusinForms.messages.minimum.format(u.minimum)}}}catch(n){return BrutusinForms.messages.invalidValue}},i.onchange=function(){var e;try{e=getValue(u,i)}catch(t){e=null}r?r[n.getValue()]=e:data=e,onDependencyChanged(o,i)},u.description&&(i.title=u.description,i.placeholder=u.description),i.onchange(),i.id=getInputId(),inputCounter++,appendChild(e,i,u),r},renderers["boolean"]=function(e,t,r,n,a){var i,o=getSchemaId(t),s=getSchema(o);if(s.required)i=document.createElement("input"),i.type="checkbox",a===!0&&(i.checked=!0);else{i=document.createElement("select");var u=document.createElement("option"),l=document.createTextNode("");l.value="",appendChild(u,l,s),appendChild(i,u,s);var d=document.createElement("option"),p=document.createTextNode(BrutusinForms.messages["true"]);d.value="true",appendChild(d,p,s),appendChild(i,d,s);var c=document.createElement("option"),m=document.createTextNode(BrutusinForms.messages["false"]);c.value="false",appendChild(c,m,s),appendChild(i,c,s),a===!0?i.selectedIndex=1:a===!1&&(i.selectedIndex=2)}i.onchange=function(){r?r[n.getValue()]=getValue(s,i):data=getValue(s,i),onDependencyChanged(o,i)},i.schema=o,i.id=getInputId(),inputCounter++,s.description&&(i.title=s.description),i.onchange(),appendChild(e,i,s)},renderers.oneOf=function(e,t,r,n,a){var i=getSchemaId(t),o=getSchema(i),s=document.createElement("select"),u=document.createElement("div");u.innerHTML="",s.type="select",s.schema=i;var l=document.createElement("option");l.value=null,appendChild(s,l,o);for(var d=0;d<o.oneOf.length;d++){var p=document.createElement("option"),c=i+"."+d,m=getSchema(c),f=document.createTextNode(m.title);if(p.value=o.oneOf[d],appendChild(p,f,o),appendChild(s,p,o),void 0!==a&&null!==a&&(o.readOnly&&(s.disabled=!0),a.hasOwnProperty("type")&&m.hasOwnProperty("properties")&&m.properties.hasOwnProperty("type"))){var h=getSchema(m.properties.type);a.type===h["enum"][0]&&(s.selectedIndex=d+1,render(null,u,t+"."+(s.selectedIndex-1),r,n,a))}}s.onchange=function(){render(null,u,t+"."+(s.selectedIndex-1),r,n,a)},appendChild(e,s,o),appendChild(e,u,o)},renderers.object=function(e,t,r,n,a){function i(e){var t=new Object;return t.getValue=function(){return e},t.onchange=function(e){},t}function o(e,t,r,n,a,i){var o=getSchemaId(r),s=getSchema(o),u=t.tBodies[0],l=document.createElement("tr"),d=document.createElement("td");d.className="add-prop-name";var p=document.createElement("table"),c=document.createElement("tr"),m=document.createElement("td"),f=document.createElement("td"),h="$"+Object.keys(e).length+"$",v=document.createElement("td");v.className="prop-value";var g=document.createElement("input");g.type="text";var y;i&&(y=RegExp(i)),g.getValidationError=function(){return g.previousValue!==g.value&&e.hasOwnProperty(g.value)?BrutusinForms.messages.addpropNameExistent:g.value?void 0:BrutusinForms.messages.addpropNameRequired};var b=createPropertyProvider(function(){if(g.value){if(!y)return g.value;if(-1!==g.value.search(y))return g.value}return h},function(t){b.getValue()!==t&&(t&&e.hasOwnProperty(t)||(t=h),(e.hasOwnProperty(t)||y&&-1===b.getValue().search(y))&&(e[b.getValue()]=e[t],delete e[t]))});g.onblur=function(){if(g.previousValue!==g.value){for(var t=g.value,r=1;g.previousValue!==t&&e.hasOwnProperty(t);)t=g.value+"("+r+")",r++;return g.value=t,b.onchange(g.previousValue),void(g.previousValue=g.value)}};var P=document.createElement("button");P.setAttribute("type","button"),P.className="remove",appendChild(P,document.createTextNode("x"),s),P.onclick=function(){delete e[g.value],t.deleteRow(l.rowIndex),g.value=null,b.onchange(g.previousValue)},appendChild(m,g,s),appendChild(f,P,s),appendChild(c,m,s),appendChild(c,f,s),appendChild(p,c,s),appendChild(d,p,s),void 0!==i&&(g.placeholder=i),appendChild(l,d,s),appendChild(l,v,s),appendChild(u,l,s),appendChild(t,u,s),render(null,v,r,e,b,a),n&&(g.value=n,g.onblur())}var s=getSchemaId(t),u=getSchema(s),l=new Object;r?(n.getValue()||0===n.getValue())&&(r[n.getValue()]=l):data=l;var d=document.createElement("table");d.className="object";var p=document.createElement("tbody");appendChild(d,p,u);var c=0;if(u.hasOwnProperty("properties")){c=u.properties.length;for(var m in u.properties){var f=document.createElement("tr"),h=document.createElement("td");h.className="prop-name";var v=t+"."+m,g=getSchema(getSchemaId(v)),y=document.createElement("td");y.className="prop-value",appendChild(p,f,g),appendChild(f,h,g),appendChild(f,y,g);var b=i(m),P=null;a&&(P=a[m]),render(h,y,v,l,b,P)}}var O=[];if(u.patternProperties||u.additionalProperties){var w=document.createElement("div");if(appendChild(w,d,u),u.patternProperties)for(var x in u.patternProperties){var C=u.patternProperties[x],E=document.createElement("div");E.className="add-pattern-div";var S=document.createElement("button");if(S.setAttribute("type","button"),S.pattern=x,S.id=t+"["+x+"]",S.onclick=function(){o(l,d,this.id,void 0,void 0,this.pattern)},(u.maxProperties||u.minProperties)&&(S.getValidationError=function(){return u.minProperties&&c+d.rows.length<u.minProperties?BrutusinForms.messages.minProperties.format(u.minProperties):u.maxProperties&&c+d.rows.length>u.maxProperties?BrutusinForms.messages.maxProperties.format(u.maxProperties):void 0}),C.description&&(S.title=C.description),appendChild(S,document.createTextNode("Add "+x),u),appendChild(E,S,u),a)for(var I in a)if(!u.properties||!u.properties.hasOwnProperty(I)){var N=RegExp(x);-1!==I.search(N)&&-1===O.indexOf(I)&&(o(l,d,t+"["+x+"]",I,a[I],x),O.push(I))}appendChild(w,E,u)}if(u.additionalProperties){var F=getSchema(u.additionalProperties),S=document.createElement("button");if(S.setAttribute("type","button"),S.onclick=function(){o(l,d,t+"[*]",void 0)},(u.maxProperties||u.minProperties)&&(S.getValidationError=function(){return u.minProperties&&c+d.rows.length<u.minProperties?BrutusinForms.messages.minProperties.format(u.minProperties):u.maxProperties&&c+d.rows.length>u.maxProperties?BrutusinForms.messages.maxProperties.format(u.maxProperties):void 0}),F.description&&(S.title=F.description),appendChild(S,document.createTextNode("Add"),u),appendChild(w,S,u),a)for(var I in a)u.properties&&u.properties.hasOwnProperty(I)||-1===O.indexOf(I)&&o(l,d,t+'["'+m+'"]',I,a[I])}appendChild(e,w,u)}else appendChild(e,d,u)},renderers.array=function(e,t,r,n,a){function i(e,t,r,n,a){var i=getSchemaId(r),o=getSchema(i),s=document.createElement("tbody"),u=document.createElement("tr");u.className="item";var l=document.createElement("td");l.className="item-index";var d=document.createElement("td");d.className="item-action";var p=document.createElement("td");p.className="item-value";var c=document.createElement("button");c.setAttribute("type","button"),c.className="remove",a===!0&&(c.disabled=!0),appendChild(c,document.createTextNode("x"),o);var m=function(){for(var e=0;e<t.rows.length;e++){var r=t.rows[e];r.cells[0].innerHTML=e+1}};c.onclick=function(){e.splice(u.rowIndex,1),t.deleteRow(u.rowIndex),m()},appendChild(d,c,o);var f=document.createTextNode(t.rows.length+1);appendChild(l,f,o),appendChild(u,l,o),appendChild(u,d,o),appendChild(u,p,o),appendChild(s,u,o),appendChild(t,s,o);var h=createPropertyProvider(function(){return u.rowIndex});render(null,p,r,e,h,n)}var o=getSchemaId(t),s=getSchema(o),u=getSchema(s.items),l=new Array;r?(n.getValue()||0===n.getValue())&&(r[n.getValue()]=l):data=l,n&&(n.onchange=function(e){delete r[e],r[n.getValue()]=l});var d=document.createElement("div"),p=document.createElement("table");p.className="array",appendChild(d,p,s),appendChild(e,d,s);var c=document.createElement("button");if(s.readOnly&&(c.disabled=!0),c.setAttribute("type","button"),c.getValidationError=function(){if(s.minItems&&s.minItems>p.rows.length)return BrutusinForms.messages.minItems.format(s.minItems);if(s.maxItems&&s.maxItems<p.rows.length)return BrutusinForms.messages.maxItems.format(s.maxItems);if(s.uniqueItems)for(var e=0;e<l.length;e++)for(var t=e+1;t<l.length;t++)if(JSON.stringify(l[e])===JSON.stringify(l[t]))return BrutusinForms.messages.uniqueItems},c.onclick=function(){i(l,p,t+"[#]",null)},u.description&&(c.title=u.description),appendChild(c,document.createTextNode(BrutusinForms.messages.addItem),s),appendChild(d,p,s),appendChild(d,c,s),a&&a instanceof Array)for(var m=0;m<a.length;m++)i(l,p,t+"["+m+"]",a[m],s.readOnly);appendChild(e,d,s)},obj.render=function(e,t){container=e,initialValue=t;var r=document.createElement("form");if(r.className="brutusin-form",r.onsubmit=function(e){return!1},container?appendChild(container,r):appendChild(document.body,r),error){var n=document.createElement("label"),a=document.createTextNode(error);appendChild(n,a),n.className="error-message",appendChild(r,n)}else render(null,r,"$",null,null);dependencyMap.hasOwnProperty("$")&&onDependencyChanged("$"),BrutusinForms.postRender&&BrutusinForms.postRender(obj)},obj.getRenderingContainer=function(){return container},obj.validate=function(){return validate(container)},obj.getData=function(){function e(t,r){if(null===s&&(s=SCHEMA_ANY),r.$ref&&(r=getDefinition(r.$ref)),t instanceof Array){if(0===t.length)return null;for(var n=new Array,a=0;a<t.length;a++)n[a]=e(t[a],r.items);return n}if(""===t)return null;if(t instanceof Object){var n=new Object,i=!1;for(var o in t)if(!o.startsWith("$")||!o.endsWith("$")){var s=null;if(r.hasOwnProperty("properties")&&r.properties.hasOwnProperty(o)&&(s=r.properties[o]),null===s&&r.hasOwnProperty("additionalProperties")&&"object"==typeof r.additionalProperties&&(s=r.additionalProperties),null===s&&r.hasOwnProperty("patternProperties"))for(var u in r.patternProperties){var l=RegExp(u);if(-1!==o.search(l)){s=r.patternProperties[u];break}}var d=e(t[o],s);null!==d&&(n[o]=d,i=!0)}return i||r.required?n:null}return t}return container?e(data,schema):null},BrutusinForms.instances[BrutusinForms.instances.length]=obj,obj},brutusin["json-forms"]=BrutusinForms}();
</script>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What I'm hoping for is the ability to build up an object dynamically without any use of arrays. In the simplest case, you might start with an empty object `{}` and then the user adds key/value pairs: `{"k1":"v1"}` after the first item is added (presuming that the structure of the value in this case is a simple string; of course the structure of the value can be anything, including complex hierarchical JSON types). Adding a second item in this example might result in `{"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for this

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "[/w/W]": {
       "type": "object"

    }
  }
}
```

`[/w/W]` means key could be any value in your root object. And `"type" : "object"` says value could be any value.

You can test this at

1. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

OR

2. https://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-06/markup/json